# Making brown clusters

Tags: nlp, hierarchical-clustering

I was playing around with P.Liang's brown clustering code [link](https://github.com/percyliang/brown-cluster). To give it a try, I induced clusters on the text of "pride and prejudice". The clusters that I got were not so good. Some examples,

> > "further agreeable attempting pleasing reference"
> >     "exempt identification deductible Service returns"
> >     "impertinence amazement amusing"
> >     "addresses astonished openly insincere conceit impertinent"

Do I need to perform some preprocessing(like removing stopwords, lemmatizing) before inducing the clusters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience you get much better clusters if you use larger values of k.  You can then use the path prefixes to trim down the number of clusters.

Answer (score 1):

ybisk has a good suggestion, when I tried to replicate your experiment I had better results with larger clusters. Some clusters are difficult to interpret, but there were a few with clear patterns, like this one for relations:

> own dear sister father mother friend sister, uncle sisters aunt
>   sister's daughter manners mother, former father, brother aunt,
>   daughters mother's dear, friends spirits cousin daughter, husband
>   Catherine, brother, sister. own, father's feelings, friend, ladyship
>   eldest thoughts friend. Catherine's sisters, side, marriage, opinion,
>   friends, acquaintance, daughters, dearest wife, daughter. vanity
>   cousin,

lemmatizing and removing punctuation/capitalization would probably improve the clusters (I'm noticing a lot of duplicate words with trailing commas/periods in my results). I'm not sure removing stopwords would help, they could contain useful contextual information (e.g. day names will appear near words like "on" more often).